# docker postgres not able to change pgdata permissions

Tags: postgresql, docker, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I have a project where I use google compute engine to host my app and docker to containerize it.

I have a postgres image and I want to use a volume to make my data persistent when I restart the container. Moreover I want the db data to be stored in google storage. So I have a google storage bucket and I have mounted a directory in my google compute engine to that bucked. Specifically what I did is `mkdir /home/vetter_leo/data` where data is the folder I want to use as a volume and then I mount it using `gcsfuse --dir-mode 777 --file-mode 777 -o allow_other --implicit-dirs  artifacts.helenos-273112.appspot.com /home/vetter_leo/data/`.

My dockerfile for the postgres image is this :

```
FROM postgres:latest

USER postgres

ENV POSTGRES_USER helenos
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD helenos
ENV POSTGRES_DB helenos
ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

COPY init_helenos_schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 5432
```

and my docker-compose file is this :

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./postgres.prod.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /home/vetter_leo/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: helenos-network
```

When doing `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --build` I end up with the container not being started and this error is shown `chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata': Operation not permitted`.

I have searched the web but so far I have not been able to find a solution for my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This approach does not seem optimal in terms of performance and data consistency because DB data will be transferred over the network on every change. Why not use a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk)?

Comment: After confirming that the persistent disk is a solution for this case, everything that did not fit in a short comment, is posted as a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a persistend disk as sugested by @mebius99 and it works so no problem anymore.